# Qt, enterEvents not sent to QLabel, why?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, event-handling, label

the code I posted below is a  simplification taken from a solitaire game project;
You can try it, copy and paste it in Qt editor;

---

I'll describe briefly **the situation** along with the issue:
You can see three labels: Label1, Label2, Label3 (I'll call them L1, L2, L3); each object (class *label* ) inherits from QLabel and reimplements some protected methods (QMouseEvent handlers) which enable drag & drop actions; both L1 and L2 can be dragged but they don't accept drop actions; L3, on the contrary, can't be dragged, yet it accepts drops; dropping label X on label Y will cause X to move on top of Y if Y accepts drops (otherwise X will return back to its starting position);
An enter event is sent to the label when the mouse cursor enters it, while a leave event is sent to the label when the mouse cursor leaves it.
Notice that when it's ok to drag, the cursor changes shape to *Qt::OpenHandCursor* (the standard cursor is *Qt::ArrowCursor*, set after *mouseReleaseEvents* and *LeaveEvents*); 
And **here's the  problem**:  drag L1 on top of L2 (clearly L1 will move back to its original position) and release without moving the cursor; now the cursor is over L2, but we entered L2 for the first time, hence Qt is supposed to deliver an *enterEvent* to L2 and a *leaveEvent* to L1; however, this won't happen (**unless you move the mouse**), so the cursor remains *Qt::ArrowCursor*; all the same we are able to drag L2;  Why didn't Qt send an enter event to L2, having the cursor left L1 and entered L2? How can I fix this?
A similar problem arises after dropping L1 (or L2) on top of L3. Now the cursor is over L1, but we already entered it, so Qt won't deliver an enter event, hence the cursor remains *Qt::ArrowCursor*. I want the cursor to change shape to *Qt::OpenHandCursor*, since we can actually drag L1;

---

**Here's what I tried**: you can send an *enterEvent* using *QApplication::sendEvent(...)*; so it suffices to check which label is under cursor (I wrote the code for *labelAtPos()* since *QApplication::widgetAt()* returns the top level widget, that is the label currently dragged, while I need the one beneath it) and send it an enter event. But this is bad because after you move the mouse Qt will automatically send both the *enterEvent* and the *leaveEvent*, thus you end up calling *enterEvent()* two times (I can't understand why Qt doesn't send them instantly instead of waiting until the mouse is moved). 
Now you could suggest: try to fake mouse movements using *cursor().setPos(...)*. That seems not to work always (I don't know why but I debugged it a lot and finally discovered it).

---

Guys **I beg** your help; Do you suggest better ways to do this? Thanks in advance. I'm using **Qt 5.6.1, OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

---

**here's my code**:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "label.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(300, 350);
    move(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center() - rect().center());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}
```

**label.h**

```
#ifndef LABEL_H
#define LABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit label(QString name, QString color, QPoint pos, bool canDrag, bool canDrop, QWidget *parent = 0);
    bool isDraggable() const;
    bool isOkToDrop() const;
    static label * labelAtPos(QPoint p, QWidget * parent, const label * w);

private:
    QString name;
    QString color;
    QPoint startDrag;
    QPoint originalPosition;
    bool canDrag;
    bool canDrop;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *);
    void enterEvent(QEvent*);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent*);

};

#endif // LABEL_H
```

**label.cpp**

```
#include "label.h"
#include <QApplication>

bool dragging = false;
#include "label.h"
#include <QApplication>

bool dragging = false;

label::label(QString n, QString c, QPoint p, bool drag, bool drop, QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    name = n;
    color = c;
    resize(80, 100);
    setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    setText(name);
    setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %1").arg(c));
    originalPosition = p;
    canDrag = drag;
    canDrop = drop;
    move(p);
}

bool label::isDraggable() const
{
    return canDrag;
}

bool label::isOkToDrop() const
{
    return canDrop;
}

void label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && isDraggable()){
        raise();
        startDrag = event->pos();
        setCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);
        dragging = true;
    }
    QLabel::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(dragging){
        QPoint p = mapToParent(event->pos());
        move(p - startDrag);
    }
    QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void label::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && dragging){
        setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        QPoint p = mapToParent(event->pos());
        label * lab = labelAtPos(p, parentWidget(), this);
        if(lab && lab->isOkToDrop()){
            move(lab->pos());
        }
        else
            move(originalPosition);
        dragging = false;
    }
    QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}

void label::enterEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    if(isDraggable())
        setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
    QLabel::enterEvent(event);
}

void label::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    QLabel::leaveEvent(event);
}

label * label::labelAtPos(QPoint p, QWidget * parent, const label * w)
{
    // it returns the first label under w, at point p, according to reverse parent's Z-order
    // if w is null, it returns the first label at point p according to reverse parent's Z-order

    label * result = 0;
    bool underw = (w == 0);
    if (parent) {
        for (int j = parent->children().count()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            label * t = qobject_cast<label *>(parent->children().at(j));
            if(t == w) underw = true;
            if (t && t != w && underw) {
                QPoint topleft = t->mapToParent(t->rect().topLeft());
                QPoint bottomRight = t->mapToParent(t->rect().bottomRight());
                QRect rect(topleft, bottomRight);
                if(rect.contains(p)){
                    result = t;
                    break;
                };
            };
        };
    };
    return result;
}
label::label(QString n, QString c, QPoint p, bool drag, bool drop, QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    name = n;
    color = c;
    resize(80, 100);
    setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    setText(name);
    setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %1").arg(c));
    originalPosition = p;
    canDrag = drag;
    canDrop = drop;
    move(p);
}

bool label::isDraggable() const
{
    return canDrag;
}

bool label::isOkToDrop() const
{
    return canDrop;
}

void label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && isDraggable()){
        raise();
        startDrag = event->pos();
        setCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);
        dragging = true;
    }
    QLabel::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(dragging){
        QPoint p = mapToParent(event->pos());
        move(p - startDrag);
    }
    QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void label::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && dragging){
        setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        QPoint p = mapToParent(event->pos());
        label * lab = labelAtPos(p, parentWidget(), this);
        if(lab && lab->isOkToDrop()){
            move(lab->pos());
        }
        else
            move(originalPosition);
        dragging = false;
    }
    QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}

void label::enterEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    if(isDraggable())
        setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
    QLabel::enterEvent(event);
}

void label::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    QLabel::leaveEvent(event);
}

label * label::labelAtPos(QPoint p, QWidget * parent, const label * w)
{
    // it returns the first label under w, at point p, according to reverse parent's Z-order
    // if w is null, it returns the first label at point p according to reverse parent's Z-order

    label * result = 0;
    bool underw = (w == 0);
    if (parent) {
        for (int j = parent->children().count()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            label * t = qobject_cast<label *>(parent->children().at(j));
            if(t == w) underw = true;
            if (t && t != w && underw) {
                QPoint topleft = t->mapToParent(t->rect().topLeft());
                QPoint bottomRight = t->mapToParent(t->rect().bottomRight());
                QRect rect(topleft, bottomRight);
                if(rect.contains(p)){
                    result = t;
                    break;
                };
            };
        };
    };
    return result;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "label.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    label lab1("Label 1", "#ff9966", QPoint(20, 20), true, false, &w);
    label lab2("Label 2", "#ccccff", QPoint(150, 20), true, false, &w);
    label lab3("Label 3", "#00cc66", QPoint(20, 150), false, true, &w);
    QLabel lab4("Label1, Label2: can drag, can't drop\nLabel3: can't drag, can drop", &w);
    lab4.resize(250, 100);
    lab4.move(20, 250);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement QHoverEvent in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411823/how-do-i-implement-qhoverevent-in-qt)

Answer (score 0):

I hit this wall a while back.  It has to do with what kinds of widgets provide hover events and enabling hover events.

```
// in your widget's constructor (probably)
this->setAttribute(WA_HOVER, true);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26392025/999943

Hope that helps.

---

UPDATE: example of forcing an additional event at the end of a mouse release:

In response to code/comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2472dcffaf703614e956380a6fd1ca7#file-label-cpp

> try dragging a label, then release out of any widget. Unfortunately no
>   hoverLeave events are sent to it. –

```
void label::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << event->type();

    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && dragging){
        //setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        unsetCursor();// unsetting the cursor is typically better than setting back to arrow
        QPoint p = mapToParent(event->pos());
        label * lab = labelAtPos(p, parentWidget(), this);
        if(lab && lab->isOkToDrop()){
            move(lab->pos());
        }
        else
        {
            move(originalPosition);
            // Force the mouse to move, too
            QCursor::setPos(QCursor::pos()+QPoint(1,1));
            // could move back with an opposite operation like -QPoint(1,1)
        }
        dragging = false;
    }
    QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

This looks like the cleanest way to get it to do the end of the drop without too much work or without it getting too messy.

Alternatives include:

Figuring out what widget you are over manually with `QApplication::widgetAt()` or something similar with the current mouse position.

Then posting the desired event using `qApp->postEvent()` followed up by `qApp->processEvents()` if necessary.  Doing a minor mouse move at the end of a release solves the issue without too much headache or introducing new bugs.

Comment: is QEvent::HoverEvent delivered to enterEvent() ?

Comment: Use the `event->type()` to figure out what it is then use that information to do a static cast.  I think it is a `mouseMoveEvent`...

Comment: I'm not receiving any HoverEvent :(. Why?

Comment: if(event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter)
        qDebug() << "HoverEnter" << "on" << name; I put this in both enterEvent() and mouseMoveEvent()

Comment: I also set mouse tracking to true;

Comment: just print out `event->type()` (not in the if statement).  What does it show?

Comment: QEvent::Type(Enter) if I enter the widget, QEvent::Type(MouseMove) if I move the cursor inside the widget;

Comment: If you want to handle the defined "hoverEvents" instead of the mixture of events that come in the enter/leave events, then you have to install an event filter.  See "QHoverEvent in QWidget" in the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26392025/999943).

Comment: Ok I'll try that; So there's no way to capture HoverEvents unless you install a filter, right?

Comment: As far as I know.  I spent a few hours coming to that conclusion last time.  I don't think much has changed since I wrote that answer forever ago.

Comment: I added a simple example here: https://gist.github.com/peteristhegreat/d6564cd0992351f98aa94f869be36f77

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate it.

Comment: here what I tried with my example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2472dcffaf703614e956380a6fd1ca7

Comment: try dragging a label, then release out of any widget. Unfortunately no hoverLeave events are sent to it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I implemented the suggested alternative since setPos seems not to work always properly as I mention in the original post. Do you think that QGraphicsScene has additional features that help to deal with this in a simpler and perhaps quicker way?

Comment: QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView is more built for layered objects and moving them around.  QWidgets lends itself more towards Layouts and forms and standard desktop looking software in general.  QML has a lot of interesting possibilities and works exceptionally well on mobile... I also did a small example of QGraphics View dragging here: https://github.com/peteristhegreat/Hexagons